# $\int f_n g \to \int fg$ in $L^1$ space

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X,Y$ be two subspaces of $L^1(0,1)$ consisting of polynomials. Define $B:X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ by $B(f,g)=\int_0^1 fg \ dt$.
>
> Is $B(f,g)$ separately continuous?

Let $f_n\in X, g\in Y$.
Suppose $f_n \to f$ pointwise.

Then how to prove
$\int_0^1 f_n g \ dt \to \int_0^1 fg \ dt$?

I want to use DCT but don't know how to bound $f_n$.

Comment: Do we even know that $fg \in L^1$?  Consider $f = g = x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Perhaps you want $f_n,f,g\in L^2$ instead.

Comment: @carmichael561 The original question is to show $B(f,g)= \int_0^1 fg dt$ is bilinear. Hence I need to show that $B_g(f_n)\to B_g(f)$. If $f,g\in L^2$, I know how to do it. But now $f,g \in L^1$.

Comment: As @anonymous pointed out, $B(f,g)$ will not be defined in general if only $f,g\in L^1$.

Comment: @carmichael561 if $f_n \in X$ and $g \in Y$ where $X,Y$ are two subspaces of $L^1(0,1)$ consisting of polynomials, is the statement true?

Comment: Well, polynomials are in $L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: @carmichael561 even in $L^2$, how do I find out a control function for $f_n$?

Comment: I think it would be best if you edited your question to clearly indicate the hypotheses you're making and what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @carmichael561 I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true, for example choose $g=1$ and $f_n(x)= (n+1)(n+2) x^n(1-x)$.

Observe that $f_n$ converges pointwise to the zero function, so $f \equiv 0$.

However,

\begin{align*}
\int _{0}^1f_n(x) \text{d}x &=\int _{0}^1 (n+1)(n+2) x^n(1-x) \text{d}x \\
&=(n+2)\int _{0}^1 (n+1) x^n \text{d}x -(n+1)\int _{0}^1 (n+2) x^{n+1} \text{d}x \\
&=(n+2)\cdot(1-0)-(n+1)\cdot(1-0)\\
&=1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

If $g$ is constantly equal to $1$ and $$f_n(t) = \begin{cases} n & \text{if } 0<t<1/n, \\ 0 & \text{if } 1/n\le t < 1, \end{cases}$$ then $\lim_n \int f_n g \ne \int (\lim_n f_n) g.$ In other words, there's no way to bound $f_n$ except when there's a way to bound $f_n.$

**PS:** I see you've edited the question to make it drastically different from what it was originally.